# How do I create vertical space between objects in a DockPanel (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I've created a basic WPF application, and a portion of my controls are set aside in a DockPanel on the left side of the screen. I'm trying to place a combobox at the top of the dockpanel, which stretches to the panel's width. Then, below that, a listview for some data. The problem is the listview is created next to the combo box instead of below it, cutting it in half. Code is as follows:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Width="200">
            <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Regions/Groups"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <ListView Height="422" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
```

Or, code without the listview:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Width="200">
            <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Regions/Groups"/>
            </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` to the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Regions/Groups"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Or just put a `StackPanel` inside the `DockPanel`:

```
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Width="200">
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Regions/Groups"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <ListView Height="422" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Aaaaaand I feel stupid and you've fixed it. That was insanely simple. Thank you!